# Can I use ForgeRock Javascript SDK directly in my angularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, forgerock

I have angular JS application where I want to integrate ForgeRock to implement authorization code grant flow using SDK provided by ForgeRock.

They are using npm to download dependencies and build the projects. I do not understand npm, and I am doing primitive style development where I write code and directly deploy those html/js file in the server.

Is it possible to use this sdk in my traditional angular js application without understanding node?

Also, does anyone know if ForgeRock AM allows for free testing of my integration before full deployment?